# Как получить информацию о месте клика в WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить информацию о месте клика при работе с WebBrowser.

```
WebBrowser.Document.ActiveElement
```

Срабатывает только на ссылках, а как можно получить информацию о теге в котором находится элемент, на который и было совершенно нажатие? Допустим мне захотелось получить исходный код тэга параграфа, в котором находится обычный текст. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `Document.GetElementFromPoint` не подойдёт?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Как-то не заметил наличие такого удобного метода.

Answer (score 2):

Вдруг кому-то пригодится

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection tags = webBrowser1.Document.All;

        foreach (HtmlElement element in tags)
        {
            element.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(element_Click);
        }
    }
    void element_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement link = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);
    }
```